# software similar to unbounce's WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: software-recommendation

Im not too good with html and graphics and usually just need to make fairly simple static pages. I was wondering if anyone knew of software that is similar to unbounce.com's WYSIWYG editor in terms of functionality and usability?

Comment: What is the end result you are looking for? Easy to use or producing a quality product? Unfortunately, those two goals tend to be diametrically opposed to each other.

Answer (score 6):

I used dreamweaver for years, and I must confess I mainly did it because inserting images and tables was terribly easy (just drag and drop), and the link between the html and the css could be done in the same page. But a WYSIWYG editor will almost always give you errors. You might not notice them if your pages are simple, but the second you want to do something a little more complex you will find them. Always do a validation after finishing a site, because editors tend to create some very strange code.

I strongly recommend you write your own html and css. It might seem like a challenge at first, but you will get used to it in **hours**, and once you've started doing it it will be WAY FASTER than any WYSIWYG. You need to have control over what you are creating, and writing it yourself will guarantee you clean, easy to read code that validates and, most importantly, you can understand. It's a step you need to take eventually, and better sooner than later!

After dreamweaver I switched to [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (free, open source), but it would probably be too drastic since it's more or less a notepad with colors. At work, I'm currently using Visual Studio because my company has a license and I work with other languages (but I'm happy with it for html). The best option is something that autocompletes some of your code: closes your divs, fills your css properties, etc. [Here are some more free editors](http://webdesign.about.com/od/windowshtmleditors/tp/free-windows-editors.htm) you can check.

Suggested by Chris Burton: Also check out [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2)

Comment: New on the market, Brackets: http://brackets.io/. Check it out!